# Aptana Studio 3 Debug server unresponsive

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, aptana3

Using  **Aptana Studio 3** to debug Ruby on Rails 4 project for the first time.
"**Debug Server**" starts the server, but doesnot stop at breakpoint and also makes the page unresponsive.

Does anyone experience same problem. Solutions/suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
The gem byebug is causing the issue.
Remove the gem , bundle install and able to debug through aptana.